# Powershell move items in subdirectories only for a folder name that contains a certain string

Tags: powershell, move

So lets say there are a bunch of folders containing different sub folders. The example below has a root folder of user 1 and 3 sub-directories under that folder. How can I create a looping script to move items from only sub-directories that contain the string "upload" up one level to the user folder.

```
->user1
--->user1upload
--->randomfolder1
--->randomfolder2
->user2
--->user2upload
--->randomfolder1
--->randomfolder2
```

So far I have the following code which moves all files in the sub-directories to the root user folder.

```
$files = Get-ChildItem '*\*\*'
Get-ChildItem $files | Move-Item -Destination { $_.Directory.Parent.FullName }
$files | Remove-Item -Recurse
```

I want to eliminate the other folders from this so that only folders with 'upload' in its name have the file contents moved up to the root user folder. How can I do this?

EDIT:
also tried this with no luck

```
$files = Get-ChildItem '*\*\*' | Select-String -Pattern "upload"
Get-ChildItem $files | Move-Item -Destination { $_.Directory.Parent.FullName }
```

EDIT2 (3/21/2019)
To be clear, his is for an SFTP program. There is a list of user folders in C:/usrs and I want to move files from c:/usrs/user1/user1upload to C:/usrs/user1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This uses PowerShell 5 to specify `-Directory`. It can be done in a different way if you are not yet to PowerShell 5.

Search for the directories, then search for files within the directories.

When you are confident the the files will be moved correctly, remove the `-WhatIf` from the `Move-Item` cmdlet.

```
Get-ChildItem -Directory -Path $Env:USERPROFILE -Filter '*upload*' |
    ForEach-Object {
        Get-ChildItem -File -Path $_.FullName |
            ForEach-Object {
                Move-Item -Path $_.FullName -Destination $_.PSParentPath -WhatIf
            }
    }
```

I thought you were in "user's" directories where you typically would not have permission to access all. One more level of directory search.

```
Get-ChildItem -Directory -Path 'C:\Users\*\*upload*' |
    ForEach-Object {
        Get-ChildItem -File -Path $_.FullName |
            ForEach-Object {
                Move-Item -Path $_.FullName -Destination $(Split-Path -Parent $_.PSParentPath) -WhatIf
            }
    }
```

Comment: This works perfectly if I set the path directly to the user root folder. How can I get it to do the loop for each root folder (e.g., user1,user2,user3..etc)?. I have to set it to C:/UPLOADS/User1 to get it to work (only works for one user).

Comment: Spoke too soon. -Recurse just puts the files back in the same location

Comment: Seems to put the files back into the same location (e.g., What if: Performing the operation "Move File" on target "Item: C:\Usrs\ddiaz\ddiazupload\test.txt Destination: C:\Usrs\ddiaz
\ddiazupload\test.txt")

Comment: @D.Diaz - Sorry. I have revised it to use the parent directory.